# Is it possible to union variable conversion function?

Tags: c++, templates

For example, there are three variable conversion functions.

```
//Int
int toInt(std::string input)
{
    int ret = strtol(input.c_str(), 0, 10);
    return ret;
}

//Double
double toDouble(std::string input)
{
    double ret = strtod(input.c_str(), 0);
    return ret;
}

//Const char*
const char* toChar(std::string input)
{
    return input.c_str();
}
```

I want to combine these functions like below:

```
~~ toConvert(std::string input)
{
    if ( Variable type is Int )
        return strtol(~~~)
    else if ( Varibale type is Double )
        return strtod(~~~)
    ...
// Using
int    i = toConvert<int>(input);
double d = toConvert<double>(input);
const char* c = toConvert<const char*>(input);
```

Is it possible?

Please help for implemet above function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "using" code is passing a template argument to `toConvert()`, so make sure `toConvert()` is actually a template, and then you can *specialize* it for each type you want, eg:

```
template<typename T>
T toConvert(std::string &input) { return T{}; /* or, throw an exception... */ }

template<>
int toConvert<int>(std::string &input)
{
    return strtol(input.c_str(), 0, 10);
}

template<>
double toConvert<double>(std::string &input)
{
    return strtod(input.c_str(), 0);
}

template<>
const char* toConvert<const char*>(std::string &input)
{
    return input.c_str();
}
```

Or, if you are using C++17 or later, you can instead use `if constexpr` in a single template:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T toConvert(std::string &input)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        return strtol(input.c_str(), 0, 10);
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        return strtod(input.c_str(), 0);
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, const char*>)
        return input.c_str();
    else
        return T{}; // or, throw an exception, or static_assert a compiler error...
}
```

Notice in either case that I changed the input parameter to `std::string&`.  Your original code was taking in the `std::string` by value, which means it takes in a *copy* of the caller's string, and so the `const char*` conversion would return a dangling pointer to invalid memory when the copied `std::string` is freed upon `return`.  By taking a reference instead, you avoid that copy.

You might be tempted to take in a `const std::string&` reference instead, but that would allow calls like `toConvert<const char*>("string")` to compile but still return a dangling pointer, since the compiler would have to create a temporary `std::string` to bind to the const reference.  But a string literal can't bind to a non-const reference.

Answer (score 3):

That's possible using C++17's `if constexpr` syntax.  For example:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool dependent_false = false;

template <typename T>
T convertTo(const std::string& input)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        return std::stoi(input);
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) {
        return std::stod(input);
    } else {
        static_assert(dependent_false<T>, "Can't convert to the specified type");
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4774d2085a69863d)

The whole `dependent_false` thing exists to make the `static_assert`ion dependent on the template parameter so that it only gets checked when the function template is instantiated.  Just an odd quirk of the C++ template rules.

---

Note that I left the `const char*` case out.  It has very different semantics from the others, since the pointer returned by `c_str` points to memory owned by the `std::string` object.

Comment: @mystes in case you are confused about the `dependent_false` portion, see [How can I create a type-dependent expression that is always false?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553) and [Of what use is a type-dependent expression that is always false?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200312-00/?p=103556)